# What is the easiest way to achieve realtime plotting in pyqtgraph

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4, pyqtgraph

I do not get how to achieve realtime plotting in pyqtgraph.
The realisation of that is not implemented in the documentation yet.

Could anyone please provide an easy example ?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Pyqtgraph only *enables* realtime plotting by being quick to draw new plot data. *How* to achieve realtime plotting is highly dependent on the details and control flow in your application.

The most common ways are:

1. Plot data within a loop that makes calls to QApplication.processEvents().

   ```
   pw = pg.plot()
   while True:
       ...
       pw.plot(x, y, clear=True)
       pg.QtGui.QApplication.processEvents()
   ```
2. Use a QTimer to make repeated calls to a function that updates the plot.

   ```
   pw = pg.plot()
   timer = pg.QtCore.QTimer()
   def update():
       pw.plot(x, y, clear=True)
   timer.timeout.connect(update)
   timer.start(16)
   ```