# PyQtGraph PlotWidget : how to force each draw (changing range) for "real time" plotting

Tags: python, plot, real-time, pyqtgraph

I'm trying to make a PlotWidget moving (from left to right) really fast like if it was an electrocariogram. Here's an example of what i want (except that he used PyQwt (which is incompatible with my projet because I use PySide (and not PyQt) and also except that I want the X axis to move from left to right too) :

[image]

However, I have no idea how to do it. I can plot the grab, i can make it move from left to right using the method :

```
 myPlotWidget.setXRange(0, 100)
```

then

```
  myPlotWidget.setXRange(1, 101)
```

Which made it looks like it moved from left to right (of 1 unit) but I don't now how to make it smooth and automatic. I tried to make a loop which looks like this :

```
 for i in range(1000):
     myPlotWidget.setXRange(10+i, 100+i, update=True)
```

But during the loop the plot is not updated... The plot is only updated when the loop is over, so I cannot see it "moving" from left to right, I just have the final result.

Someone can help me on this? Is there any way I can force the redraw the 1000 times of the loop?

I was first thinking it was computing too fast so I tried this

```
 for i in range(1000):
     myPlotWidget.setXRange(10+i, 100+i, update=True)
     time.sleep
```

but of course it didn't work.

Thank you so much for your help !

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18080170/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-achieve-realtime-plotting-in-pyqtgraph

Answer (score -1):

At the end of the loop, when it is updated, you have something like `myPlotWidget.update()`, or `myPlotWidget.canvas.draw()`, right?

Just move that into the for loop. This will get slow if you are trying to plot a large amount of data though.

Comment: No; QWidget.update() only _schedules_ a repaint for later. You must call QApplication.processEvents() or return to the Qt event loop.

Comment: Luke is right, thank you so much for your help. It works perfectly with QApplication.processEvents(). Can you post it as an answer (not a comment) of the question for possible future people having the same question. I ll be glad to check it as an "usefull answer" :) Thank you again